# Using react API to print a question on screen not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm new to using react and I'm trying to make an application that shows the user a question from this api: https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1 and after the user clicks the button it should show a new question. I keep getting invalid hook call and after trying to find the answer I just can't seem to find out why.
Heres my code:

````
  
  

    function FetchQuestion(){
    const [triviaq, setTriviaq] = React.useState([]);


    React.useEffect(() => {
      //fetch
      fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setTriviaq(data.results[0].question);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }, []);

    

    return(
    
    <div>
      Question: {triviaq}
     <button onClick={FetchQuestion}> Next Question </button>
      
      </div>
    )

    }
    
    
  
  ReactDOM.render(<FetchQuestion/>, document.getElementById("root"))
  
  </script>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are trying to call your own react component instead of calling a function which you should define inside your component to trigger during `onClick` event.
Additionally, here you're using `useEffect` without any dependency on it, in order to call it only during the initial rendering.
Create a separate function to be called during initial rendering and `onClick` event as follows.

```
export default function FetchQuestion() {
  const [triviaq, setTriviaq] = React.useState([]);

  const fetchNextQuestion = () => {
    //fetch
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTriviaq(data.results[0].question);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchNextQuestion();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Question: {triviaq}
      <button onClick={fetchNextQuestion}> Next Question </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope this would solve your issue.